# UICollectionView with autosizing cell (estimatedSize) and sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds goes mental

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Consider the following situation. I have an `UICollectionView` (inside `UICollectionViewController`), which looks almost the same as `UITableView` (the reason why I don't use `UITalbeView` is because I have non data views on layout, that I don't want to manage and mess with my `IndexPath`). 
In order to achieve the autosizing cells I've set `estimatedItemSize`, something like that:

```
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 72)
```

Also, in my cell I have layout attributes:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

So, by doing that I've got exact layout as `UITableView` with autosizing. And it works perfectly.

Now, I am trying to add the header and pin it on scrolling to the top of the section, like that:

```
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = false
```

but layout goes into weird state, I have glitches all over the place, cells overlapping each other, and headers sometimes doesn't stick.

UPDATE:

The code of view controller and cell:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0, height: 36) // enables dynamic height
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(indexPath.row * 10 % 100) + 10 // Random constraint to make dynamic height work

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath)
}

class CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell {
let identifier = "CustomCell"

@IBOutlet weak var rectangle: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

[image: Animation of result]

Details of lagging in video: https://vimeo.com/203284395

Comment: adding some images for reference would help us to visualize the problem you are having

Comment: Will you attach a screenshot?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but part of the problem could be that you're setting `layout.estimatedItemSize` based on `self.view.bounds.size.width`.  If you're using autolayout, it's counterintuitive where `width` is valid.  What you're doing is essentially recursive:  You set something based on `width`, which then causes the view to be resized, which causes `width` to change. Try removing that circular dependency.

Comment: No, it is not right. Bounds width has nothing to do with cells layout. Layout only affect sizing and position of cells, but not the size and position of collection view itself. Also, self.view is super view of collection view here, so it doesn't matter at all. It is just a constant.

Comment: @PavelGatilov  Add your UI images and some piece of code work what you have so that we can estimate the requirement preciously and provides you best answer otherwise answer will be assumptions .

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy updated

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog updated

Comment: @PavelGatilov What is the issue? it seems ok. and explain why you are not using tableView. I didn't get your reason what you write in question.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy header disappearing, spacing is changing every time. Header is jumping and changing position

Comment: @PavelGatilov header is not disapearing it just moving above.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I've attached the video for you, so you can see a lot of lags  https://vimeo.com/203284395

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135277/discussion-between-the-dahiya-boy-and-pavel-gatilov).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update from WWDC 2017:

My colleague was on WWDC 2017, and he asked one of the UIKit engineers about this issue. The engineer confirmed that this issue is known bug by Apple and there is no fix at that moment.

Comment: Anything new on this one?

Answer (score -2):

Use the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        //Calculate your Dynamic Size Here for Each Cell at SpecificIndexPath.
        //For Example You want your Cell Height to be dynamic with Respect to indexPath.row number
        let cellWidth = collectionView?.bounds.size.width
        //Now Simply return these CellWidth and Height, and you are Good to go.
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        //You Can Pass TextField As Well as i have considered UITextView for now.
        let cellSize = self. calculateSize(cellTextView: cell.textView, cellText: yourArrayOfText[indexPath.row], withFixedWidth: cellWidth)
        return cellSize
    }
```

And do not change the Cell Height by changing the Constraint.constant directly. Instead of this simply use Above Delegate method to change height. Changing Cell Constraint can cause issues like this.

Use bellow method to get your desired Size.

```
   func calculateSize(cellTextView: UITextView, cellText: String, withFixedWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
            let textView = UITextView()
            textView.text = cellText
            textView.frame = cellTextView.frame
            textView.font = cellTextView.font
            textView.tag = cellTextView.tag
            let fixedWidth = withFixedWidth
            textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
            var newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
            return newSize
        }
```

Use Bellow method to calculate the image size.

```
//Method to Calculate ImageSize.
func calculateImageSize(image: UIImage) -> CGSize {
        var newSize = image.size
        if newSize.width > (ChatView.maxWidth - 70) {
            newSize.width = ChatView.maxWidth - 70
            newSize.height = ChatView.maxWidth - 70
        }
        if newSize.height < 60 {
            newSize.height = 60
            newSize.width = 60
        }
        return newSize
    }
```

Comment: Ok. You don't get it. The constraint just represents the part of logic. It could be driven by anything dynamic like text amount inside label or images etc.

Comment: So you want to change the size of Cell with Respect to text in it??

Comment: Not necessarily text, but yes, the idea behind to change the cell size based on the size of content inside. And when I adding sticking headers it goes all wrong.

Comment: Now check my Answer. I have made a method to get a size of TextView with respect to text. Logic is that create an empty cell and pass the textView of Cell to the method along text and width.
Now you can create a new textView and assign font size, font type to textView of cell to this new textView and calculate the height.
Now simply return that height and fixed width to the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method. You will now get an idea how to do this.

Comment: I have attached the method to calculate the image Size as well.

Comment: That is huge code smell. 
Initiate text view every time when you want to layout the cell is bad idea, it will cause serious performance problems

Comment: Then take a global textView and just change the font and text every time. You will be good to go.

Comment: It is still a code smell. Using and object to do what it is not design to do is a bad programming style. Also it doesn't solve the problem of how to layout multiple views holding different content.